# I have an error when selecting a value on primefaces picklist

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I trying a primefaces showcase of a pickList. When I select a country on the pickList, I automatically get this error :

```
com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickList.validateValue(PickList.java:134)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1040)
        at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickList.validate(PickList.java:175)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1341)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:631)
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1736)
```

When I debug on that first line of the error (at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickList.validateValue(PickList.java:134)), I see that oldModel is populated but newModel is null..

Here is my entire code :

```
  <h:form>
            <pf:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" escape="false"/> 

            <div class="card">
                <h5>Advanced</h5>

                <pf:pickList id="pojoPickList" value="#{pickListView.countries}" var="country"
                            itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" showSourceControls="true"
                            showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true"
                            showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                            converter="countryConverter" responsive="true">

                    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Starting</f:facet>

                    <pf:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListView.onTransfer}" update="msg"/>
                    <pf:ajax event="select" listener="#{pickListView.onSelect}" update="msg"/>
                    <pf:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{pickListView.onUnselect}" update="msg"/>
                    <pf:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{pickListView.onReorder}" update="msg"/>

                    <pf:column style="width:94%">
                        <div class="flex align-items-center">
                            <span class="flag flag-#{country.code} mr-2" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{country.name}"/>
                        </div>
                    </pf:column>
                </pf:pickList>
            </div>

        </h:form>
```

```
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.TransferEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
 
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PickListView {

    @Inject
    private CountryService service; 
    private DualListModel<Country> countries;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {   
        //Countries
        List<Country> countriesSource = service.getCountries().subList(0, 10);
        List<Country> countriesTarget = new ArrayList<>();

        countries = new DualListModel<>(countriesSource, countriesTarget);

    }
     public CountryService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(CountryService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public DualListModel<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(DualListModel<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
            builder.append(((Country) item).getName()).append("<br />");
        }

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        msg.setSummary("Items Transferred");
        msg.setDetail(builder.toString());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onSelect(SelectEvent<Country> event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item Selected", event.getObject().getName()));
    }

    public void onUnselect(UnselectEvent<Country> event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item Unselected", event.getObject().getName()));
    }

    public void onReorder() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "List Reordered", null));
    }
}
```

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class CountryService {

    private List<Country> countries;
    private Map<Integer, Country> countriesAsMap;
    private List<Country> locales;
    private Map<Integer, Country> localesAsMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        locales = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] isoCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (int i = 0; i < isoCodes.length; i++) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", isoCodes[i]);
            countries.add(new Country(i, locale));
        }

        Collections.sort(countries, (Country c1, Country c2) -> c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName()));

        int i = 0;
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.US));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.FRANCE));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.GERMANY));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.ITALY));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.KOREA));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("es", "ES")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ca", "ES")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("nl", "NL")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pt", "BR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pt", "PT")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ar", "SA"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("cs", "CZ")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("el", "GR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("fa", "IR"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hi", "IN")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("in", "ID")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hr", "HR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hu", "HU")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("iw", "IL"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ka", "GE")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("lt", "LT")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("lv", "LV")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("no", "NO")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pl", "PL")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ro", "RO")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ru", "RU")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sk", "SK")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sl", "SI")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sr", "RS")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sv", "SE")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("tr", "TR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("uk", "UA")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("vi", "VN")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE));
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return new ArrayList<>(countries);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Country> getCountriesAsMap() {
        if (countriesAsMap == null) {
            countriesAsMap = getCountries().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getId, country -> country));
        }
        return countriesAsMap;
    }

    public List<Country> getLocales() {
        return new ArrayList<>(locales);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Country> getLocalesAsMap() {
        if (localesAsMap == null) {
            localesAsMap = getLocales().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getId, country -> country));
        }
        return localesAsMap;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage; 
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@Named
@FacesConverter(value = "countryConverter", managed = true)
public class CountryConverter implements Converter<Country> {

    @Inject
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Override
    public Country getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                return countryService.getCountriesAsMap().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid country."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Country value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return String.valueOf(value.getId());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Country implements Serializable, Comparable<Country> {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private Locale locale;
    private boolean rtl;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(int id, Locale locale) {
        this(id, locale.getDisplayCountry(), locale.getCountry().toLowerCase(), locale);
    }

    public Country(int id, Locale locale, boolean rtl) {
        this(id, locale.getDisplayCountry(), locale.getCountry().toLowerCase(), locale);
        this.rtl = rtl;
    }

    public Country(int id, String name, String code) {
        this(id, name, code, null);
    }

    public Country(int id, String name, String code, Locale locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale == null ? "en" : locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public String getDisplayLanguage() {
        return locale == null ? "English" : locale.getDisplayLanguage();
    }

    public boolean isRtl() {
        return rtl;
    }

    public void setRtl(boolean rtl) {
        this.rtl = rtl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Country country = (Country) o;
        return id == country.id
                && Objects.equals(name, country.name)
                && Objects.equals(code, country.code);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, code);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. What versions are you using?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Java SE experts will not be able to answer this question. Instead please add version info.

Comment: Have you tried changing the RequestScoped implementation or with a different scope?